# Dictionary from a FASTA sequence

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I am trying to create a dictionary from a FASTA sequence. But I keep getting the same error saying that a variable is not defined, even though it is defined. Can someone please help me understand if this code is right?

```
#!/usr/bin/pyhton
# Build a dictionary containing all sequences from a FASTA file from typing import List



try:
    f= open("FASTA.rtf",'r')
except IOError:
    print('The file "FASTA" does not exist')

seqs = {}
for line in f:
    # Let's discard the newline at the end (if any)
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line[0]==">": #or line.startswith('>')
        words=line.split()
        name= words[0][1:]
        seqs[name]=""
    else: #sequence, not header
        seqs[name]=seqs[name]+line

for name,seq in seqs.items():
    print(name,seq)
```

Comment: If the first line doesn't start with '>', then `name` isn't defined.

Comment: And if the first line does start with '>', please let us know what the error message is.  I'll also know that "python" is misspelled the #! line, but that's probably not your problem.

Comment: Hey Frank, Thank you for your help.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/victoriavelazquez/PycharmProjects/Basic projects/Reading a FASTA File.py", line 15, in <module>
    if line[0]==">": #or line.startswith('>')
IndexError: string index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: So you really want `line.startswith(">")`.  You've got an empty line and there is no `line[0]`.

Comment: Ok, so I changed it to line.startswith ('>') but now I am having problems with unhashable types. It says that sees [name] is a list. But what if I want to print the characters of the FASTA sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, why are you using a FASTA in an `.rtf` (rich text format) and not `.fa`/`.fasta` or `.fq`/`.fastq`? That might be causing some of your problems. Below is a snippet of code that I used to edit the gene labels of a FASTA file in-place.

```
def remove_trailing_inplace(filename):

    with fileinput.input(files=str(filename), inplace=True, backup=".bak") as f
        for line in f:
            if line[0] == ">": # only engages with lines that have genes
                a = line.split(" ") # series of splits to properly modify each
                idx = a[0].split(".")[0]
                gene = a[3].split(".")[0]
                rest = " ".join(a[4:])
                print(idx + " " + a[1] + " " + a[2] + " " + gene + " " + rest.str)
            else:
                print(line, end="")
```

This snippet of code works just fine and catches all of the genes I need. The biggest difference is this takes the FASTA file directly, and not an rtf in fasta format. Also, I don't use any sort of stripping: the FASTA format does not need it, as far as I am aware.

Additionally, as @Frank Yellin commented, your `if/else` statement is logically incorrect, because in the `else` portion, you are attempting to use `name`, which is only defined in the `if` portion. `if` and `else` statements are mutually exclusive, so you cannot rely on variables declared in one in the other.

Luckily the fix is not too difficult. What I would recommend is declaring `name` at the start of the loop (outside the `if/else`).

```
seqs = {}
names = []
for line in f:
    
    if line[0]==">":
        words=line.split()
        name= words[0][1:]
        names.append(name)
        seqs[name]=""
    else: #sequence, not header
        seqs[names[-1]]=seqs[name[-1]]+line
```

While shoddy coding, this should should avoid the name errors. Additionally, because FASTAs are the way they are, we can assume we always have a '>' to start.

EDIT: For further clarification for those who are unfamiliar with the FASTA format, here is an example from wikipedia:

```
>SEQUENCE_1
SATVSEINSETDFVAKNDQFIALTKDTTAHIQSNSLQSVEELHSSTINGVKFEEYLKSQI
ATIGENLVVRRFATLKAGANGVVNGYIHTNGRVGVVIAAACDSAEVASKSRDLLRQICMH
```

Where the line with `>` contains sequence information, while all lines after (until the next '>') represent the sequence itself. Thus, we can always assume we will never hit another sequence until we are done with the first sequence. This is why the above code works, and why using `names[-1]` is okay.

Comment: As correctly pointed out at the end of your answer, your solution using a `names` list relies on correct fasta formatting. But please note that correct formatting should also ensure a `name` variable is defined before it is used. So using a list doesn't solve any problem here.

Comment: To elaborate on my comment: The `name` variable defined in the `if` branch of the first iteration of the `for` loop will persist and still exist at further iterations of the loop, when the `else` branch will be reached. Storing the name in a list is unnecessary.